# how to prove the existence of a solution from an infinite linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove the existence of a solution for variables $x_j$ with $j=1,2,3,\cdots,\infty$ from the linear system

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty A_{i,j}x_j=b_i    (i=1,2,3,\cdots,\infty)$$

Where $A$ is a square matrix.

Question: Is it enough to show that $\det A\not =0$, such that $A^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: Yes just show $\det A \neq 0$

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $j$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$, how can $A$ be a square matrix?

Comment: @Michael The matrix elements of $A$ is $A_{i,j}$, where $i,j=1,2,\cdots,\infty$. So matrix $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: @Michael I added the range for index $i$ as well. Thanks-

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about the determinants of infinite matrices.

Comment: I take my answer back, the matter need more consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what assumptions you are making, but the most elementary result in this direction is if $A=I-B$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $B=(b_{ij})$ with 
$\sum_{ij} |b_{ij}^2| < 1$ then $A^{-1}$ exists and the solutions to the trundicated finite case limits to a solution to the infinite case.
The result is not hard to see from the equation in analogy from geometric series
$$\frac{1}{I-B}=1+B+B^2+B^3 \cdots$$
the series converges by assumption on $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check if my $A$ has this nice property.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus Thank you for this useful answer, may I ask where I can find a relatively detailed discussion on this topic? Thank you very much.